# How to import .DB file by connecting MYSQL in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a `.db` file like `"sakila"`

```r
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)

mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '123456', dbname = 'sakila',host = 'localhost')
dbListTables(mysqlconnection)
```

It reports the error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'sakila.db'

How do I fix it?

I hope to import the `.db` file in Mysql by using R.

Comment: MySQL is a server level RDBMS and not a file-level RDBMS like SQLite or MS Access. Your `.db` file may be an SQLite database. Also, your code does not show `sakila.db` as indicated in error.

Comment: So what should I do?  I tried sakila.db and it still in error.  Do I need to import .db in MYSQL workbench?

Comment: I also find a tutor resource in: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_database.htm     why it cannot work?

Comment: If you are on macos or linux, try on the command-line (not R): `file sakila.db`. It might return something indicating what type of monolithic file-based database it is.

Comment: What to do? First, find out what exactly is the .db file. Where did it derive? How was it created? Is it a binary file or text file with SQL commands? If it is indeed an SQLite file, then use SQLite libraries like `RSQLite`.

Comment: I know, I mean how do I use mysql to open it ?  Do I need to find the sakila.sql and then import it to mysql workbench and then connect it by R?   Cause in this task , our professor asked to "Do each experiment twice: once in SQLite and once in MySQL by using R " . However, he only give a sakila.db file. So I post this question, hope to know "how to connect  the .db file in Mysql by using R." I have already know how to connet it by using RSQlite:```{r}
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = "sakila.db")
dbListTables(db)
```

Comment: You still have not answered the question: *what kind of file is `sakila.db`?* If it's SQL code, then read it in and execute it on normal connections to the database, do not try to use `dbname="sakila.db"` in the connection instantiation as that makes no sense. If it's not SQL code, then ... I don't know.